# NSUser defaults save total score

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

Is there a way to save the total score for each game played using NSUser defaults?

I have this which adds 1 point for each second in gameplay:

```
let waitScore = SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0) //add score every second
let incrementScore = SKAction.runBlock ({
    ++self.score
    self.scoreLabel.text = "\(self.score)"}) 
self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([waitScore,incrementScore])))
```

How would i go about adding this onto a total score each time the game ends so i can load the total score in the main screen? i'm thinking about making extra scenes available when the score gets to a certain point. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the score like this, and summon *increasePoint* or *storeUserPoints(0)* and in main screen do getUserPoints()

```
func getUserPoints()->Int{
    return NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("userPoints") ?? 0
}

func increasePoints(pointsToAdd:Int){
    storeUserPoints(getUserPoints()+pointsToAdd)
}

func storeUserPoints(points:Int){
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(points, forKey: "userPoints");
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function below can be used for score keeping with `NSUserDefaults`.
It takes the current score (S) compares it to a highscore value (hs). It then returns and stores the score as the highscore only if it is higher than they highscore.

```
func gameDidEnd(S: Int) -> Int {        
    /* load score data */
    let ud = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if ud.valueForKey("score") == nil { ud.setInteger(S, forKey: "score") }
    let hs = ud.integerForKey("score")
    if S > hs {
        ud.setInteger(S, forKey: "score")
        return S
        println("NEW HIGHSCORE!")
    } else {
        return hs
    }
    self.score.text = "\(S)"
}
```